# OS X server for launching Unit Test remotly

Tags: ios, unit-testing, osx-server, kiwi

We have a various of choice to use remote OSX Server like
 MacinCloud,
 MacStadium,
 vmOSX,
 Xcloud, Xcodeclub

I want to use Kiwi.

If anyone can suggest I would be appriciate

Answer (score 0):

Try MacinCloud, you may need the their dedicated server to run the kiwi.